# Printing emails

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, printing

When printing emails, we usually get

```
Name
---
From:
Sent:
To:
Subject:
```

at the top of the page.  However, after composing an email, some users want to print the email before sending it and they have noticed that those emails only print with the following details

```
Name
---
To:
Subject:
```

Is it at all possible to change this so even though they haven't sent the email yet, they still get the `From:` bit at the top, as in:

```
Name
---
From:
To:
Subject:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. The cause of the issue is Outlook that doesn't set From until the message is sent. There are reasons for this: in some cases From can be set by transport only (i.e. Exchange Server). So the only way to have full details is to print messages from Sent Items folder.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.pc.cc.ca.us/TLC/docs/PrintBCCAddressesEmailMessageOutlook2010.pdf) file/guide I found describes the method for adding BCC to a form, and allows you to add From: as well, so you should follow this to set up the form, and I tried getting the preview from it, and it does add the from field to the print-out.

[Source](http://www.pc.cc.ca.us/TLC/docs/PrintBCCAddressesEmailMessageOutlook2010.pdf)

Essentially:

1. Open the message
2. Click the Developer tab.
3. If you don't have the Developer tab, add it by clicking File > Options > Customize Ribbon. In the list to the right, under Customize the Ribbon, check the box next to Developer, click OK, then click the Developer Tab.
4. Click the Design this Form button.
5. Select Address Fields from the dropdown menu
6. Drag the From field and drop it above the To field.

(other options are available according to the guide, follow that for that)

7. click Run This Form from the ribbon.

8+. There ya go!